# what does the following command do in git?

Tags: git

I saw a tutorials of git, it initialize the repo by the command `git-init-db`, I know the `git-init` will initialize the repo, but what the additional `-db` will do?

Comment: What tutorial was this is? Did it not give any explanation? Are there spaces in the command or not (`git -init -db` vs. `git-init-db`)? Is there a hyphen before `init` in the tutorial? What happens when you try it?

Comment: woah guys what is up with the rapid downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

You are referring to the [`git-init-db`](http://mirrors.stuhome.net/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.4.3.2/git-init-db.html) command.

Comment: yes, I think so, but it complains that git-init-db command not found, I am using 1.7.12

Answer (score 3):

In very early versions of Git, the command names were all prefixed with `git-`, as in `git-add`, `git-commit`, `git-init-db`, etc. Years ago these were all changed so that the main command is just `git`, and the `add`, `commit`, etc. were arguments to the `git` command. So you would have `git add`, `git commit`, `git init-db`, etc.

Similarly, the `git-init-db` command was a low level way of initialising a Git repository. The `git init` command was introduced to do the same thing that `git-init-db` does, plus a few more required steps.

I must conclude that you are perhaps reading a *very* old Git tutorial. I recommend something like the [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book.

Answer (score 0):

It will fail. Both the `-d` and the `-b` options are unknown to git. At least to version 1.7.10.4 which I use. As to `git-init-db`, you can invoke it as `git init-db` which the is same as `git init`. Or probably it's the "plumbing" for the "porcelaine".